# VB.NET - Return a 2D array of numbers from a function

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET - Return a 2D array of numbers from a function

I have a function that produces a set of x and y coordinates in a 2D array but I cannot find a method of returning the coordinates.

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve but this produces the following error: Value of type 'Double(*,*)' cannot be converted to 'Double'.

```
Function myFunc(ByVal myVar As Double) As Double

    Dim myArr(2, 1) As Double

    myArr(0, 0) = 1 * myVar
    myArr(1, 0) = 2 * myVar
    myArr(2, 0) = 3 * myVar
    myArr(0, 1) = 4 * myVar
    myArr(1, 1) = 5 * myVar
    myArr(2, 1) = 6 * myVar

    Return myArr

End Function
```

I have tried a number of different methods but am only new to VB and may be 
missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message tells you whats wrong.  Your function is defined `As Double` but you are trying to return `Double(,)`.  Thus, define the function `As Double(,)`

Comment: If I change the function to `As Double(,)` it still produces the same error. I believe that I am defining myArr as different to the function return definition but don't know how to rectify it.

Comment: Not in the code showing there you dont.  Its showing elsewhere now isnt it?

Comment: @Shaun - Why did you edit the question so that it made it invalid? I rolled it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `Double(,)`, not `Double`. It should be:

```
Function myFunc(ByVal myVar As Double) As Double(,)

    Dim myArr(2, 1) As Double

    myArr(0, 0) = 1 * myVar
    myArr(1, 0) = 2 * myVar
    myArr(2, 0) = 3 * myVar
    myArr(0, 1) = 4 * myVar
    myArr(1, 1) = 5 * myVar
    myArr(2, 1) = 6 * myVar

    Return myArr

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the first time I tried that it produced the same error but that was due to my method of calling the function rather than the function itself. My Bad.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it through changing the function and myArr definition from `Double` to `Object`. The result from the function is then the complete array, but stored as an object. Don't know if this is the best method but it works.

```
Function myFunc(ByVal myVar As Double) As Object

Dim myArr(2, 1) As Object

myArr(0, 0) = 1 * myVar
myArr(1, 0) = 2 * myVar
myArr(2, 0) = 3 * myVar
myArr(0, 1) = 4 * myVar
myArr(1, 1) = 5 * myVar
myArr(2, 1) = 6 * myVar

Return myArr

End Function
```

Comment: This is not the way to go. You should be returning `Double(,)`, not `Object`.